# Angular custom checkbox directive doesnt work in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, checkbox

I have created a custom directive for checkbox which can be used across my application. i have created the checkbox with the following code.

**JS**

```
angular.module("myApp")
    .component("ngCheckbox", {
       template:
           '<div class="ng-control-checkbox">' +
           '<input id="check" type="checkbox" data-ng-model="$ctrl.checked" class="checkbox">' +
           '<label for="check">'+
           '<span data-ng-bind="$ctrl.label"></span>' +
           '</label>' +
           '</div>' +
           '',   

        bindings: {
            label: '=?',
            checked: '='
        },
        controller: function () {
            var $ctrl = this;
        }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
  .ng-checkbox label{
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .ng-checkbox label:before {
     content: "\e911";
     cursor: pointer;
     color: #84919A;
  }
  .checkbox {
    display: none;
  }
  .checkbox:checked + label:before {
   content: "\e910";
    cursor: pointer;
    color: $color_forest_green;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
      <div data-ng-repeat="notification in notificationList" >
        <ng-checkbox data-checked="notification.selected"></ng-checkbox>
      <div>
```

- Im using CSS ::before to change the content. i do not want to write any JS for this.
- i cant change the HTML structure as i have to use the application specific icons as CSS content for the checkbox

**Issue**

As i am binding the ***id*** of the checkbox with the ***for*** of the label i am not able to use this checkbox directive inside ng-repeat. i am hoping to get a solution for this as i am stuck on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a dynamic ID, either auto-incremented every time there's an instance of the checkbox, or base it off of the current ngRepeat iteration and pass it into the directive.

Alternatively, you could just structure the HTML so that the label implicitly links to the input without an ID at all. Wrapping the label around the input should do that.